# real time updates for new page events

Tags: facebook, real-time-updates

I know there's a few questions knocking around on this topic but none quite the same.

I'm currently searching by location for all the pages relating to a particular geographic location and caching their events in a database. The problem being I have to currently loop through all the pages i'm watching frequently to check for updates.

At the moment the >10,000 Pages I'm keeping track of takes a good while to update. It would be much neater (and nicer to fb) to be notified instead of polling.

Does anyone know of a more efficient to do this?

Thanks

Ben

Comment: Let me know if I'm wrong, but is this actually just the feature request? :) If so, this isn't the best place to post this - it's meant to be only for programming Q&A related to the Facebook API or social plugins.

Comment: Real-time updates for pages only cover the page’s public properties, but not feed content or events yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is an API called [Real-time Updates](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/). You will have to register an http-server. Facebook will send a POST request with the related changes. You cannot subscribe to all connections but events are okay. I haven't tried it but it should work for you.

Searching for "[facebook] real time updates events" here on Stack Overflow gives 5000+ results. So I think, there should be some usable code somewhere.

Comment: I've already investigated real time updates and as above have seen that the Events relationship isn't published. I was just after a 2nd opinion on if there is a better way than mass-polling